# Incorrect signature on a list of objects

Tags: apex

I have a class that looks the following:

```
public class ChatBot_GetLocalAndTripID {
    public class ChatBotInput{
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public string SelectedStrips;
    }
    
    public class ChatBotOutput{
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public string LocalCallCenter;
        
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public string TripID;
    }
    
    @InvocableMethod(Label = 'Get Trip Info' description='Get a list of Trips From BO for specific user')
    public static List<ChatBotOutput> GetTrips (List <ChatBotInput> SelectedStrips){
        system.debug(SelectedStrips);
        ChatBotOutput result = new ChatBotOutput();
        result.LocalCallCenter = 'Israel';
        result.TripID = '34344344';
        return new List<ChatBotOutput> {result};         
    }

}
```

It is expecting a list of ChatBotInput ...

In my test I am getting the error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void GetTrips(List<chatBot_GetLocalAndTripsIDTest.ChatBotInput>) from the type ChatBot_GetLocalAndTripID`

Please explain me what I do not understand here ?
here is my test:

```java
@isTest
public class chatBot_GetLocalAndTripsIDTest {
    public class ChatBotInput{
        public string SelectedStrips;
    }

    @isTest static void testMethodCon() {
        List<ChatBotInput> toInput = new List<ChatBotInput>();
        ChatBotInput SelectedTrip = new ChatBotInput();
        SelectedTrip.SelectedStrips = 'Athens - 2022-06-30';
        toInput.add(SelectedTrip);
        //ChatBotInput result = new ChatBotInput();

        Test.startTest();
      
        system.debug('Start testing');
        ChatBot_GetLocalAndTripID.GetTrips(toInput);

        Test.stopTest();        
    }
}
```

Working Test:

```
@isTest
public class chatBot_GetLocalAndTripsIDTest {
    @isTest static void testMethodCon() {
        
        
        List <ChatBot_GetLocalAndTripID.ChatBotInput> finalInput = new List <ChatBot_GetLocalAndTripID.ChatBotInput>();
        ChatBot_GetLocalAndTripID.ChatBotInput toInput = new ChatBot_GetLocalAndTripID.ChatBotInput();
        toInput.SelectedStrips = 'Athens - 2022-06-30';
        finalInput.add(toInput);
        Test.startTest();
      
        system.debug('Start testing');
        ChatBot_GetLocalAndTripID.GetTrips(finalInput);

        Test.stopTest();        
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Why do you appear to have a nested method declaration? And why have you hidden the ChatBotInput definition by redeclaring it in the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public class ChatBotInput` [shadows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm) the other `ChatBotInput` class. Remove that class from your unit test class. Your unit test should reference either `ChatBot_GetLocalAndTripID.ChatBotInput` or `ChatBotInput`, depending on if the class is a nested class or top-level class, respectively.

Comment: I used ChatBot_GetLocalAndTripID.ChatBotInput and this one worked. I ll update my question with my working code. Thx again @sfdcfox